# Armature exports broken

Tags: armature, export, import

Hello I created this model (Each arm and leg is separate armature) For some reason it exporting it and importing it turns into this:

Model being export:
[image]

Model Imported:

[image]

for some reason some hands are detached even though they should have a constraint extra bones are added and some Ik's don't work. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Hello, could you please share the imported version?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=P5j9VNQz" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/P5j9VNQz/)

Comment: Are you sure that you need several armatures? Actually the hand is detached because the arm has location keyframe that put it away from the hand, if you want to put the hand at the tip of the arm then keyframe the hand at the correct location? This is a quick fix but I guess it would be better to have only one armature

Comment: I have it under multiple armatures because parented even the claw and arm together with deform it, so I rather constrained them to each other would there be a better solution? I really appreciate the help

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, if you have no particular reason to have several armatures, then use one only (join all these armatures into one)

Comment: I see what you mean now, this works thanks!